# django ajax collection change

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have list of articles on the page in table and i want to sort it with ajax by clicking on the button.

I use dajaxice, it sends request to ajax.py to **example1** method and gets responce JSON data in **my_js_callback**

HTML:

```
<script>
function my_js_callback(data) {
    alert(data)
    $("#article_view_tbody").html("")
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
         article=data[i]
     $("#article_view_tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].title...) // here i need to set url for article edit
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="Dajaxice.content.example1(my_js_callback);">Click Me!</button>
<table>
<tbody id="article_view_tbody">
    {% for article in articles %}
        <tr>
            <a class="article_link" href="{% url article_detail article.id %}">
                    {{ article.title }}
        </a>
            </td>
         </tr> ...
```

ajax.py:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core import serializers
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from models import Article

def get_by_date_queryset():
      return Article.objects.all().order_by('created_on')

@dajaxice_register    
def example1(request):
    """ Handling sorting requests """
    queryset = get_by_date_queryset()
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    return json_serializer.serialize(queryset, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I can't pass {% url %} tags in the JS. 
SO is it a way to reload tbody with ajax without js data appending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simply serializing the queryset and returning it, you could return a list containing each element in the following format:

```
    return [
        {
            'pk': article.pk,
            'title': article.title,
            'url': reverse('view_article', args=(article.pk,))  # Or, use article.get_absolute_url()
        }
    for article in queryset]
```

You can simply loop through the JSON returned, using JavaScript, and use `articles[i].url` in your `for(var i = 0;...` loop to get the URL, title, etc.

#### Update (re: "bad way to hardcode"):

Simply use:

```
serialized = json_serializer.serialize(queryset, ensure_ascii=False)
loaded = json.loads(serialized)
for row in loaded:
    row['url'] = reverse('view_article', args=(row['pk'],))
return json.dumps(loaded)
```

That also serves to separate the `"fields"` from the `"url"` (feels more correct).

Comment: And if i have 10-20 fields or i will add some fields tomorrow? This is a bad way to hardcode fields of the model in the method

Comment: @Feanor - you can just as easily add the URL to the serialized queryset, then. See my updated answer.